# Laravel Sanctum Token and Session

Tags: php, laravel, api, session, token

I am implementing Laravel Sanctum API in my service but I am having some issues with sessions. Let me explain:

I need to save some data for each user who authenticates via token. Now, if the token doesn't exist but the session does, the Sanctum middleware routes still pass. I have read that the session comes into play if the token is not present, but this is incorrect because the token should be valid for the duration of the session. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Laravel just cares if the user is logged in. Token or session, doesn't matter. By default, [tokens don't expire](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#token-expiration), as they're intended for long-term logins like a mobile app or API integration. They have no concept of a session duration.

Comment: So, should I remove the expiration limit of the session and not let it expire?

Comment: Your web users will likely use Sanctum's single-page-app support (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) via sessions. You don't need to manage tokens for these users, and the session expires automatically. You'd use a Sanctum *token* typically for an app that consumes the API, like a mobile app or a third-party who wants to build an integration.

Comment: I have to use Laravel Sanctum because the APIs provided are for a mobile and desktop app. However, I need to be able to store variables for each user who logs in. That's why I was saving them in the session using code like Session::put('globalVarForUser', 'varContent'). So how can I achieve this without using sessions if I switch to using tokens?

Comment: Tokens are intended for stateless usage. You don't have a session when using an access token to hit an API. Store it in the User model, or store it on the client.

Comment: Sure. Do you say it is a good practice to create a "data" column in JSON format in the Sanctum token migration and customize the model? On the client side, it seems difficult to me, but this data is fundamental for developing the API service and for testing.